# Как отфильтровать правильно данные в Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Хочу отфильтровать данные так:

```
{{base_url}}/models?source=0&search=Олег Киселев
```

чтобы фильтровалось сначала по `source`
, а потом уже по `search`

То есть, как и `last_name` (Киселев) так и `first_name` (Олег) так и **вместе**.

Попытки к этому есть:
Но этот запрос не работает так как надо, находит только по `first_name`, а `last_name` не учитывается

```php
public function index(Request $request): AnonymousResourceCollection
    {
        return IndexResource::collection(
            Model::query()
                ->whereSource(SourceEnum::LARAVEL)
                ->whereFilter('source', $request->get('source'))
                ->orwhereLikeFilter('first_name', $request->get('search'))
                ->orwhereLikeFilter('last_name', $request->get('search'))
                ->paginate(25)
        );
    }
```

`orWhereLikeFilter` и `whereFilter` - это обычный where с like. Написан Trait.

Comment: так может надо олег киселев сначала разделить на два слова, а потом одно подставлять в фильтр фамилии, а второе в имя?

Comment: @teran Так не получиться, могут вписать и Киселев Олег. Не определить, что является именем, а что фамилией

Comment: и то и другое тогда ищите в каждом столбце.